# how to set select option selected by value from database?

Tags: jquery, selection, selected, cordova-2.0.0

I have created registration page and Edit page which contains 3 select options. While registering a user I store the data in database which contains the select option value when user click on the edit page I am able to fill the text fields with the data that I fetch from data base but I am not able to select the   select option which the value that I get from data base the code which I used to do this is:

the `company` variable store the data of option value from data base

```
<select name="select-choice-a" id="select-choice-a" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="a">
     <option>Select Company</option>
        <option value="standard">facebook</option>
        <option value="rush">Linked In</option>
        <option value="express">Skype</option>
        <option value="overnight">Twitter</option>
    </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function fetchdetails(){
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql(select_details,[ids,nam1],function(tx,results){
        for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
        first_name=results.rows.item(i).frist_name;
        last_name=results.rows.item(i).last_name;
        company=results.rows.item(i).company;
        title=results.rows.item(i).title;
        industry=results.rows.item(i).industry;
        owner=results.rows.item(i).owner;
        email=results.rows.item(i).email;
        landline=results.rows.item(i).landline;
        mobile_no=results.rows.item(i).mobile;
        fax_no=results.rows.item(i).fax_no;
        website=results.rows.item(i).website;
        street=results.rows.item(i).street_name;
        city=results.rows.item(i).city;
        region=results.rows.item(i).region;
        pincode=results.rows.item(i).pincode;
        country=results.rows.item(i).country;
        linkedin=results.rows.item(i).linkedin_link;
        twitter=results.rows.item(i).twitter_link;
        facebook=results.rows.item(i).facebook_link;
        skype=results.rows.item(i).skype_link;
        additionalinfo=results.rows.item(i).additional_info;

        }
    });
});
}

var index='';
var x=document.getElementById('select-choice-a');
alert(x.options.length);
for(var i=0;i<x.options.length;i++){
    if(x.options[i].value===company)
        {
        alert("I am in select option"); 
        index=i;
        alert("index of select-choice-a"+index);
        break;
        }
}
x.options[index].selected=true;
```

Comment: What you want to do?, please clerify

Comment: What i want is when user select the edit option the edit page will be open and that page will contain the data from the data base. i am able to set the fields with data from data base I also want that the select option to set selected with the value that i get from the data base.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code

```
var index='';
var x=document.getElementById('select-choice-a');
alert(x.options.length);
for(var i=0;i<x.options.length;i++){
    if(x.options[i].value===company)
        {
        alert("I am in select option"); 
        index=i;
        alert("index of select-choice-a"+Index);
        break;
        }
}
x.options[index].selected=true;
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var company='';
fetchdetails();
var x=document.getElementById('select-choice-a');
var index=0;
for(var i=0;i<x.options.length;i++){
    if(x.options[i].value===company)
        {
        alert("I am in select option"); 
        index=i;
        alert("index of select-choice-a"+index);
        break;
        }
}
x.options[index].selected=true;
</script>
```

Comment: i used this method to set select option var x=2;
  document.getElementById("select-choice-a").selectedIndex=x; its working on browser but when run it on emulator its not working. I mean it doesn't the set selection option selected.

Comment: @NeeravShah, What value contain company variable? is it "standard" or "facebook" ??

Comment: company variable contains standard value.

Comment: hey i tried it's working but can you tell me why its not working when i try to load it company value from database. means i call a function which fetch data from data base and then it should set the select option selected to that value.

Comment: @NeeravShah, write your code which load value into company variable.

Comment: @NeeravShah, Is fetchdetails() javascript function? if yes, the how tx.executeSql possible? I thinks its PHP function. so you have to store php variable into Javascript. then you can access it

Comment: no its not Php function its a javascript function which iam using to fect the data from the local database table. I will explain you the flow first it will display a listview of registered user when user select a user it will store name and id of the selected user and will load a edit page in this page onload function is called to fetch the data from the temp table an data will be use to calll the main table to fetch complete row of the user which was selected.

Comment: @NeeravShah, you're missing something big here, there are multiple record and you have just overwrite each time into 'company' variable..

Comment: @NeeravShah, if it is okey, then you should call fetchdetails() function first, and also you should declare `var company='';` variable before function.

Comment: I had declared the var company='' and can you tell me how to call the fetch details function first bcz when i load the page first i call  getdetails function and then i call the fetch details function  and below fetch details function i had return the select option code.

Comment: And if  i put the select option code in to function its not working.

Comment: if i call fetch detail function here than its not returning back to select-option bcz once's it enters in fetch details function than it call fill details function where it fill the text fields with the data fetch from data base.

Comment: @NeeravShah, you must have to select atleast one time fetchdetails() function, without calling how you fill value into company variable?

Comment: i call fetch details option but its not returning back to select option it just complete the function execution and load the edit page.

Comment: ok tell me one thing that fetch details function and the select option has to places in the same script

Comment: @NeeravShah, yes you can. but make sure not goes into fetchdetails() infinite loop

Comment: ok i had tried but still the problem is same know when i call fetch details it execute the function but does not call the the for loop in the select option. can you give and example if possible.

Comment: create jsFiddle or phpFiddle whichever suite for your data or upload at any live server. so i can view & test @NeeravShah

Comment: sorry i dont know how to create a jsfiddle file.